# C: Getting user input , storing , continueing then displaying last 50 inputs

Tags: c, string, io, copy

```
#define HISTORY_SIZE 50
#define INPUT_SIZE 512   /*Max input size*/
char input[INPUT_SIZE];  /*Holding user input globaly*/
char* input_history[HISTORY_SIZE];
```

This is how im storing my input in to input, and wanting to store a copy of it in to input_history

```
 void addToHistory()
 {
/*input_history[currentHistorySize++] = strtok(input,"\n");*/
input_history[currentHistorySize++] = input;
printf("ADDEDTOHISTORY: %s \t\t %d \n", input_history[(currentHistorySize- 1)],currentHistorySize);

 }
```

But when i go to print it out, it doesnt work ....

```
/*strcpy(input,input_history[currentHistorySize-2]);
printf("LAST INPUT, %s \n %s \n \n", input,input_history[currentHistorySize-2]);*/

printf("0: %s \n ", input_history[0]);
printf("1: %s \n ", input_history[1]);
printf("2: %s \n ", input_history[2]);
```

Ive been sitting trying to work this out for ages and cant seem to see where im going wrong, maybe a pair of new eyes will notice some silly mistake?

Basicly i want to take the users input using

```
fgets(input,INPUT_SIZE,stdin)
```

Then store a copy of it into char* input_history
And then be able to print it out later on.

Very simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you're not actually copying the string, you're just copying the pointer (the address of the string). Try this instead:

```
input_history[currentHistorySize] = malloc(strlen(input) + 1);
strcpy(input_history[currentHistorySize], input);
currentHistorySize++;
```

Or maybe:

```
input_history[currentHistorySize] = strdup(input);
```

You should also remember to free them when you're done.

Answer (score 3):

One issue is definitely here :

```
input_history[currentHistorySize++] = input;
```

Eventually all your history is going to reference to the same memory location, which is `input`
Create  a new char array and copy input into it, then reference to the new array.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
input_history[currentHistorySize++] = input;
```

use

```
sprintf(input_history[currentHistorySize++],"%s",input);
```

Assuming that `input_history` is initialized.
However, this doesn't take care that the size of `input` is less or equal than the capacity of `input_history[x]`. It's up to you to check.

Comment: assuming input_history is initialized

Comment: @UmNyobe yes, of course. I added your note in the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `input_history` variable is an array of pointers, you can't just assign your input like this: `input_history[currentHistorySize++] = input;`

Read up on pointers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)

And then go ahead and use one of the C standard library functions, e.g. `strndup()`: http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup

Answer (score 1):

This is a pointer assignment, not a string copy:

```
input_history[currentHistorySize++] = input;
```

resulting in all elements in `input_history` pointing to `input`.

You could use `strdup()` to copy the string:

```
input_history[currentHistorySize++] = strdup(input);
```

or `malloc()` and `strcpy()`. Remember to `free()` the elements of `input_history` when no longer required.